# .NET 7 JWT authentication unable to decode the header as base64url encoded string

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I'm currently trying to implement JWT authentication in my .NET 7 web API. The authentication part of things actually works, the error is with the refresh token logic.

When the user tries to refresh the token I'm trying to validate the token despite it being expired but I keep getting an exception. It can validate the token when making requests so I must be doing something wrong if it's failing manually.

TOKEN GENERATION

```
private async Task<string> GetAuthToken(User user)
        {
            //Get all necessary configuration values
            var secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SuperSecretSecretKey");
            var audience = "audience";
            var issuer = "issuer";
            var tokenValidTo = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);

            //Get claims identity to add to the token
            var claimsIdentity = await GetClaimsIdentityAsync(user);

            //Create the jwt token definition
            var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateJwtSecurityToken(
                issuer,
                audience,
                claimsIdentity,
                DateTime.UtcNow,
                tokenValidTo,
                DateTime.UtcNow,
                new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            );

            //Create the token
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(jwtToken);

            return token;
        }
```

TOKEN VALIDATION

```
private ClaimsPrincipal? GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(string? token)
        {
            try
            {
                var secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SuperSecretSecretKey");
                var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "issuer",
                    ValidAudience = "audience",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretKey)
                    ValidateLifetime = false
                };

                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out var securityToken);

                if (securityToken is not JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid token");

                return principal;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

EXAMPLE TOKEN

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3ciLCJ1c2VySWQiOiIxIiwibmJmIjoxNjgyOTM4MzI0LCJleHAiOjE2ODI5MzgzODQsImlhdCI6MTY4MjkzODMyNCwiaXNzIjoiaXNzdWVyIiwiYXVkIjoiYXVkaWVuY2UifQ.oF2mDCj-QrW1RA2zChA-2aJUuGjWvQpj6L8gRn7AT20
```

EXCEPTION

```
IDX12729: Unable to decode the header 'eyjhbgcioijiuzi1niisinr5cci6ikpxvcj9' as Base64Url encoded string. jwtEncodedString: 'eyjhbgcioijiuzi1niisinr5cci6ikpxvcj9.eyj1bmlxdwvfbmftzsi6inn0ywnrb3zlcmzsb3cilcj1c2vyswqioiixiiwibmjmijoxnjgyotm4mzi0lcjlehaioje2odi5mzgzodqsimlhdci6mty4mjkzodmyncwiaxnzijoiaxnzdwvyiiwiyxvkijoiyxvkawvuy2uifq.of2mdcj-qrw1ra2zcha-2ajuugjwvqpj6l8grn7at20'.
```

INNER EXCEPTION

```
Invalid property identifier character: (. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

STACKTRACE

```
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken.Decode(String[] tokenParts, String rawData)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(String token)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.GetJwtSecurityTokenFromToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateJWS(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration currentConfiguration, SecurityToken& signatureValidatedToken, ExceptionDispatchInfo& exceptionThrown)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, JwtSecurityToken outerToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& signatureValidatedToken)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at ....AuthorizationService.GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(String token) in ...\AuthorizationService.cs:line 228
```

I've been staring at this error for hours and I cannot figure out what's going on so any help at all would be really appreciated. I've done a lot of googling and unfortunately can't find a lot of information about this error.

Comment: Why is the JWT token in the exception all lower case while your example token is mixed case? Your example token can be debugged in [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io), the token as shown in the exception can't. Are you performing some magic before you call the GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken method?  Where does that jwt token get mangled?

Comment: No transformation happening, only thing that happens is this in my controller  `var token = Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString().Substring("Bearer ".Length);` I see what you mean though, never even noticed the lowercase token in the exception

Comment: It seems quite unusual, that the exception logs the token in lowercase unless it is actually in lowercase. Did you log the incoming token in `Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString()` and see what it looks like?

Comment: Yea it's in the correct format, checked it from the postman request right through to calling ValidateToken. Agree that it's weird for it to be in lowercase and the error message makes a lot more sense when you consider it is in lowercase and also weird that the authentication middleware works which calls the same ValidateToken method presumably on the same token

Comment: First of all when checking token for permission in that scnario are you getting the your claim accordingly? Or only in case of refresh token you are getting the exception?

Comment: @Ryan Did you find a solution to this?